# Create a unique ID for my child key in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My users can create jobs. I want to add these jobs to my Firebase DB. I want the structure of the DB to look like this

```
- jobs
--uid
---name
---descritpion
---...
```

For the "uid", I'd like a random and unique string. Is it possible to generate it automatically somehow instead of generating a random number by myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    String key = database.getReference("jobs").push().getKey();
```

get the instance of firebase and get reference to child jobs then get the key. the key will be unique.